# Buffer conversion decodes correctly the <Topic> in a PUB/SUB, but not the messages. Why?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

This is the code for a SUB-side handler of a ZeroMQ PUB / SUB socket:

```
sock.on('message', function(topic, message) {
  console.log("--Topic--");
  console.log(topic);
  console.log(topic.toString('utf8'));
  console.log("--Message--");
  console.log(message);
  console.log(message.toString('utf8'));
  console.log("");
});
```

Probably missing something here, but I am having a hard time working out why my buffer conversion is returning junk:

```
--Topic--
<Buffer 70 72 65 73 65 6e 63 65>
presence
--Message--
<Buffer 08 a0 43 10 f9 dd d3 cb 05 18 00 20 18 2a 06 00 0c 29 f2 d5 b4 aa 1f 30 10 00 1a 14 13 00 b3 75 48 ec 55 a7 92 a2 bd ee 9d 4b b6 25 a0 77 a5 d3 22 0c ... >
�C���� *
        )�մ�0�uH�U������K�%�w��"
                                Aruba AP 215*
��۟
```

The first item (topic) decodes without issue, but the message doesn't seem to.

Comment: Can you post what you're sending? It looks like you're sending binary data

Comment: String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(message))

Comment: @Darkrum this is the result with your amendments:    
`ÞI¹äÓË 3*.
         )òÕ´ª0«i!×Jêgº!¥hÝ"
                               Aruba AP 215*
¬£Û`

Comment: @MiguelMota I don't have access to the source messages unfortunately

Comment: you need to know what type of data it is to properly decode it

Comment: @Oliver what is the message original? can you post the whole buffer value please.

Comment: @MiguelMota if it helps, I have a sample piece of code that is used for this application. Trying to pin point the encoding type: https://gist.github.com/Oliverr/698eb76db7306dfa2f8e5c2c3579548f

Comment: I found this while googling parts of the source code https://d1x3hnhct7p62q.cloudfront.net/SupportSite/ProductionFiles/e90ec26d-8a7f-4610-9a6b-b9aa8f338a35/ALE_1.1UG-API-Guide.pdf?Expires=1500839752&Signature=JiY2JDW0qBuyuzHQ7G9RYxIt2P2jXro-zbTYObZMoHF2dw5rBSbDQF40N-1dN3m0TpKK4mGkghY9wYexcmY4lF-42Omh~BayXy6H1DNLoHipNU3uHnBunuj9DaXtq3Ga5QSDCEX8iZmcYX4O1j4Z4tZxp4pTMgyiFp8UjmUiFhodM-q6GXXwm1Ivb9DbjunZGreOCp8BznBZ1zgREyXyYE3~YaisbQDDoVAQ0N8F4zdTsmjca7EzWes2rCPIIUAgHEC1aNbZ3MbUTAcBk6oTTHePRCixGS3XebSsHvsHYboTzTEUKwUNsZsIbsbSjsicZ3H7zfEfsgrbAjNMP0Oxvg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJCOCR7KIA7QV5SEQ

Comment: The message is compressed using Google's Protobuf https://github.com/google/protobuf

Comment: @MiguelMota interesting. Not familiar with protobuf. Do I need to locate the schema file?

Comment: @Oliver check this out http://yura415.github.io/js-protobuf-encode-decode/

Comment: @Oliver that online tool uses this library https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/

Comment: @MiguelMota just pulled that in, and managed to locate the schema for the product. Getting errors that seem to relate to the scheme/message now: `RangeError: index out of range: 73 + 10 > 73`

Comment: Note: this is the relevant schema. 

`message proximity {
        optional mac_address sta_eth_mac = 1;
        optional mac_address radio_mac = 2;
        optional int32 rssi_val = 3;
        optional string ap_name = 4;
 optional bytes hashed_sta_eth_mac = 5;
}`

Comment: Would you mind to keep **MCVE**-based posts? If your so far reported use-case is not complete, as having a part of it outside of your control, then **first** mock-up a complete use-case of your own, i.e. with also a mock-up sender - a PUB-process ( implemented in any language of your choice ) and validate your intended SUB-side behaviour against that PUB. After this full-MCVE works E2E, start to decide, where the problem originates. ZeroMQ need not be the first one to start complaining about junk-data with. Ok?